# Nginx append an argument to static content

Tags: nginx, swagger-ui

In the swagger ui you can append an custom url eg:*http://petstore.swagger.io/index.html*?url=mydomain.com/json

Now I have the swagger ui static content running on my nginx server and when I access 
mydomain.com/api/docs/?url=mydomain.com/json I get the correct content of my api.

Now I would like to simplyfy to allow the user to type only **mydomain.com/api/docs/** and nginx should append the argument ?url=mydomain.com/json at the end.

I tried it with set args and with rewrite but with rewrite I get `alias" cannot be used in location "/api/docs/" where URI was rewritten`.

How can I append a parameter to static content?

```
  server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ${HOSTNAME};

  location / {
    autoindex on;
    root  /www/myapp/;
  }

  location /api/docs/ {        
    #set $args ?url=mydomain.com/json;
    rewrite /api/docs/$ /api/docs/?url=mydomain.com/json break;
    autoindex on;
    alias  /www/api-docs/;
  }
```

Comment: How does swagger read parameters? If it reads them in browser using javascript then you're doing something meaningless.

Comment: well I guess its JS. here is an example http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=baaam

Comment: Then you don't need to do anything with nginx. You should modify your app that it acts as if it has url parameter even if it's not.

Comment: I don't want to change the static files because I have different url and i would like to solve this with ngix by appending a url to the query and reuse /www/api-docs/ and not duplicate it

Comment: Well, then you need to check if argument exists and _redirect_ if it doesn't